# Building Radio group at run time android

Tags: android, android-edittext, radio-group

I'm building the layout at run time, i have to show a radio group with 4 radio buttons for the user , but some times i should show an Edit Field with the radio button so the user can write some thing related to that radio button in the edit box.
I want the edit field to appear beside the radio button ,.
I tried to build the edit field but it keeps showing under the radio group, and if i sepereate one of the buttons in a linear layout with the edit text, it become out of the scope for the radio group.
this is the code for building the radio group

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(context);
    radioGroup.setContentDescription(id);

     for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(context);
    radioButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    radioButton.setText("" + vector.get(i).getQ_text());

    radioButton.setContentDescription(vector.get(i).getA_id());
    radioButton.setTextSize(20);
    radioButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A5462E"));
    radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    radioGroup.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
```

How can i build the edit field at run time to be shown next to the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create the layout for each row of your `RadioGroup` in a xml file like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then in your loop you can inflate this layout and do what do you want with it:

```
    final LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    final RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        final LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item_radio_button, null);
        final RadioButton button = (RadioButton) item.findViewById(R.id.button);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) item.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        button.setText("Test");

        // Your condition to show or not the editText
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        radioGroup.addView(item);
    }
    root.addView(radioGroup);
```